# Convert python variables into javascript variables

Tags: javascript, python, google-visualization

I want to use Google Chart API using javascript. (I don't want to use the python wrapper)
So how do I send data from my python code into the javascript to create graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate Python data to Javascript data types with JSON ( http://docs.python.org/library/json.html ).  I assume you're using this alongside a Python-based web server?